# Where should gradle external build files live?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to import an external file into my build.gradle e.g.

```
apply from 'other.gradle'
```

Will it only look for the file in the current directory?

How can you setup a common well known place for external build files to live? Putting the  full path to other.gradle in the build.gradle works e.g.

```
apply from '///C:/Users/me/.gradle/other.gradle'
```

but users on different OS's may have different paths.

I tried adding a property in gradle.properties and and using it in build.gradle but it didn't work:

```
local_build_system="///C:/Users/me/.gradle"

apply from: '${local_build_system}/other.gradle'
```

I get the following output:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'helloworld'.
> Could not read script 'C:\Users\me\workspace\helloworld\${local_build_system}\other.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

I assume the property isn't resolved at the point of execution of 'apply' as the property can be printed out from a task just fine

```
println "local_build_system ${local_build_system}"
```

#### Edited to Add:

The reason I'm attempting this is from reading the user guide (chapter 59 http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html) where it says "Shared scripts. Define common configuration in an external build, and apply the script to multiple projects, possibly across different builds."

Comment: Use double quotes if you want to interpolate variables inside the string (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to the build script. By convention, script plugins go into `$rootDir/gradle`, which means they can be applied with `apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/someScript.gradle"`. Script plugins are typically stored in the project's source repository, and aren't shared across builds (unless perhaps if multiple builds share the same source repository). As Radim already said, String interpolation is only supported for double-quoted String literals.

Comment: So does that imply that cross project script logic should go into an overarching root project of which all other projects can get their common logic? I'm actually looking at chapter 59 http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html which defines: "Shared scripts. Define common configuration in an external build, and apply the script to multiple projects, possibly across different builds." I read that as 'it's possible to define build logic that's external to all projects'

Comment: I don't understand your first question. (Gradle terminology: A *build* has one or more *projects*.) The user guide should say "define common configuration in an external build *script*". It's technically possible to share such a script across builds, but unless these builds are in the same source code repository, how would you make it available on every machine? Scripts can be applied over HTTP, but aren't currently cached when doing so. Therefore, in practice build logic that needs to be shared across builds is almost always shared as a binary plugin (plugin class that ships as a Jar).

Answer (score 0):

I've actually got this working using a file URL:

```
apply from: "file:///${local_build_system}/other.gradle"
```

gradle.properties:

```
local_build_system="C:/Users/me/.gradle"
```

Whether this is the correct or best way to share logic across builds I don't know, but perhaps there is no correct or best way in gradle?